# Back button- how to track and prepopulate values(from database)

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a requirement to design 2 lightning pages, the first lightning page takes contact details and saves it in the db and navigates the user to the 2nd page on click of a button.

On the 2nd page, a form from a formbuilder is embedded on a lightning page and asks for more questions. However, when the user clicks backbutton on this page, the user must be taken back to the lightning page prepopulating with data he filled.
Any ideas around how to track the back button and since the data is in the db, can I prepopulate it?

Comment: Have you considered using a screen-based Flow to fulfill this need? It doesn't seem like a very Lightning design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is because you can most certainly pre-populate a form with latest values from the database. Have you considered [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) or [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example)? There is a lot of documentation around those two. Here is a sample from Salesforce docs for your quick reference:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">

    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler"
      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
      layoutType="FULL"
      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
      targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
      mode="EDIT"
      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
      />

    <!-- Display a lightning card with details about the record -->
    <div class="Record Details"> 
        <lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="{!v.simpleRecord.Name}" >
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
                    <lightning:formattedText title="Billing State" value="{!v.simpleRecord.BillingState}" /></p>
                <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
                    <lightning:formattedText title="Billing City" value="{!v.simpleRecord.BillingCity}" /></p>
            </div>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>

    <!-- Display an editing form -->
    <div class="Record Details">
        <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Edit Account">
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
               <lightning:input label="Account Name" value="{!v.simpleRecord.Name}"/>
               <br/>
               <lightning:button label="Save Account" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
            </div>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            {!v.recordError}</div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

The only issue I see you might end up with is that your back button could be pre-populating the form with stale data. If that happens, you need to figure out a way to re-initialize that component on the press of the back button. Perhaps [re-create the component on the fly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) or consider `aura:method` to call init logic explicitly?